# Log parsing issue for dynamically mapped fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

We are continuously receiving errors at the logstash with the following entry:

`"Could not dynamically add mapping for field [app.kubernetes.io/created-by]. Existing mapping for [kubernetes.labels.app] must be of type object but found [keyword]."}}}}`

Can anyone please help with parsing the field "kubernetes.labels.app.kubernetes.io/created-by" correctly. The entry is taken as flat field, we should either convert it to separated out format or else rename it to "kubernetes.labels.app_created-by" .

We did try with the rename processor as like below in the existing ingest pipeline:

```
{
        "rename": {
          "field": "kubernetes.labels.app.kubernetes.io/created-by",
          "target_field": "kubernetes.labels.app_created_by"
        }
 }
```

and also with the mutate filter at logstash as like:

```
mutate
  {
   rename => { "[kubernetes][labels][app.kubernetes.io/created-by]" => "[kubernetes][labels][app_created-by]"
  }
```

Both of these are not helping us to fix the issue either.

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

Since you have dynamic mapping enabled it seems that elastic first received a document looking like this:

```json
{
  "kubernetes": {
    "labels": {
      "app": "some name"
    }
  }
}
```

Which lead elastic automatic parsing to assume `kubernetes.labels.app` was a keyword.

Now it is receiving a new documents with this layout:

```json
{
  "kubernetes": {
    "labels": {
      "app": {
        "kubernetes": {
          "io/created-by": "a date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the mapping is not to happy about it.

## Solution

I would need a sample of the document to explain more.